# Presence of image control in VC++2008

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi

Hello Everyone,
               I want to know if there is an image control in VC++ like there is one in VB. Actually using the picture box i face the problem of not being able to re size the image at design time for my dialog. But in image control this is possible. I there is no image control is there a way to check the height and width of a dialog from the dialog editor at design time ???

Comment: Which GUI framework are you using? There are so many.

Comment: @David Hefferman what do mean by GUI framework?? How do I check which one I am using? I am using the standard toolbox present in the VC++2008 Professional Edition Dialog Editor.

Comment: OK, you are using raw win32. Unlucky for you! You can display an image in a STATIC control.

Comment: well thanks I guess there is no other solution is there?

Answer (score 0):

If you're writing an unmanaged C or C++ project it's a little bit more difficult than using the PictureBox control that would be available when designing managed Windows Forms application, but still doable.

If you are using a DialogBox resource for the window (note: I wrote this part using Visual Studio 2015 as a reference, not 2008, but the general process should be the same):

1. Insert the image as a resource in your project.  Let's say we named the resource for the bitmap `IDB_BITMAP1` for simplicity.
2. Create a new `Static` child window in the dialog box.
3. Right click on the new `Static` window and select `Properties`.
4. Under the `Misc` subheading in `Properties`, change `Type` to `Bitmap`.
5. Under the `Misc` subheading in `Properties`, change `Image` to `IDB_BITMAP1`.

If you are hand-coding the window (i.e. manually writing calls to `CreateWindow` and `CreateWindowEx` to create the window):

1. Insert the image as a resource in your project. Make sure to add the line `#include "resource.h"` to your code.
2. Get a handle to the bitmap using the `LoadBitmap` function.
3. Create the static window as a child window of the main window, and specify the `SS_BITMAP` window style.
4. Send the `STM_SETIMAGE` message to the window using the previously identified handle to the bitmap resource.

Example code, assuming your image is `IDB_BITMAP1`:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include "resource.h"

int APIENTRY _tWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPTSTR lpCmdLine, int nShowCmd)
{
    HWND hWnd, hStcImage;
    MSG Msg;
    HBITMAP hBitmap = LoadBitmap(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDB_BITMAP1));

    // ... register the window class etc

    hWnd = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, _T("ExampleClassName"), _T("Simple Window"), WS_VISIBLE | WS_SYSMENU, 100, 100, 350, 370, NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);
    hStcImage = CreateWindow(_T("Static"), NULL, WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | SS_BITMAP, 10, 10, 0, 0, hWnd, NULL, hInstance, NULL);
    SendMessage(hStcImage, STM_SETIMAGE, (WPARAM)IMAGE_BITMAP, (LPARAM)hBitmap);

    ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_SHOW);
    UpdateWindow(hWnd);

    while (GetMessage(&Msg, NULL, 0, 0) > 0)
    {
        TranslateMessage(&Msg);
        DispatchMessage(&Msg);
    }
    return Msg.wParam;
}
```